# Heegaard Fleor Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the opposite direction any diagram $(\sum_ g, \alpha_1, ..., \alpha_g, \beta_1, ..., \beta_g)$ where
the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ curves satisfy the first two conditions in Definition 2.3 determine
uniquely a Heegaard decomposition and therefore a 3-manifold.

Why is statement correct? This statement is in "An introduction to Heegaard Fleor homology" article, page 4, written with ozvath and szabo.

Comment: If you attach disks along $\alpha$ curves in one side and disks along $\beta$ curves in other side, and now take a small $\epsilon$ -nbd of that, then the boundary of both of the sides are $S^2$. So you can cap it off in a unique way, the interesting part is 'why is this unique'? THINK!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\sum_g$ be a torus. if attach a $D^2$ along $\alpha$, remaineded a $D^3$, this remainded space uniquely fill by a $D^3$ and for $\beta$ we can doing manner again. Similar we can do it  for$\sum_g$ be a surface by genus g.